# Some file operations with DocumentsProvider API on Android

Tags: android, mime

DocumentsProvider API is the only official way to manage files on the removable storage since Android 5.0. But, seems, it does not support even basic functionality. Or, maybe, I missed something?

1. Create a new document (file) with a non-standard extension.
   `DocumentsContract.createDocument(contentResolver, uri, mimeType, name)`
   appends an extension according to the mimeType. For example, it adds `.txt` for 'text/plain' MIME-type. The question is: Can I create a file with the name `file.abc`? If no, can I register a new MIME-type, which will be linked to `abc` extension?
2. Move a document.
   `DocumentsContract.renameDocument(contentResolver, uri, newName)`
   can rename a document. But can I move a document into another directory (change the parent of the document)? Must I create a new document, copy the content from the old one, and delete the old document?
3. Set the modification date of the document.
   This operation can be useful in some situation. For example, in the case I must emulate filesystem `move` operation for the question 2. Is there a way to set any required modification time for a document?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can, but it also depends on how DocumentProvider is implemented by the device manufacturer.
2. You can only rename, its parent cannot be moved. You're right about creating a new document.
3. No, setting last modified date is not allowed till Android 6.0. Maybe in future.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you provide a bit more details for the item 1? 'Yes' is about `abc` MIME-type support out of box by a particular manufacturer? Or 'yes' about ability to register any MIME-type, but it is restricted by some manufacturers?

Comment: I believe mime type is only used to store it inside android media DB. For extension, your file name must contain it. Like abc.txt or abc.blahblah.

Comment: Actually, DocumentProvider appends an extension to the name according to the specified MIME-type. As an example for 'text/plain', if I put `file` as a name, a file `file.txt` is created. If I put `file.abc`, a file `file.abc.txt` is created. That's the problem of item 1. For compatibility, I need to manage files with unregistered extensions. And I see no workarounds.

Comment: I do not have this problem. Currently, I can't see the code I'm using. But I will update later.

Comment: I confirm the problem with extensions on some Android API 21. It ignores my .jpg extension and replaces by its own .jpeg

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems to append its own extension at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! But I cannot close the question because no solution, nor workaround available for item 1. It blocks me from using DocumentsProvider API.

Comment: FWIW, I noticed that for an `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);` if you then set                 `i.setType("text/something");` that `.something` will be used as the extension.  For example, `text/xml` results in a .xml extension. `text/html` gives you a .html extension, and `text/myextension` resulted in a .myextension being appended.  This is with api 23.  Didn't check earlier versions yet. 'text/plain' does result in .txt tho.  Did you try 'text/abc'?